# Natbib creates questions marks with knitr in RMarkdown

Tags: pdf, natbib, knitr, pandoc, markdown

I am writing a paper in RMarkdown with knitr and pandoc. My references are saved as a .bib file. All files are in the same folder. With the default pandoc citation system, both the bibliography at the end and the citation in-text show up properly:

```
---
title: I am a title
author: Mr. Author
output:
  pdf_document:
bibliography: ~/framingstudy.bib
---

Authors say many things [@aaroe11].
```

[image]

With natbib, however, neither of them show up:

```
---
title: I am a title
author: Mr. Author
output:
  pdf_document:
    citation_package: natbib
bibliography: ~/framingstudy.bib
biblio-style: apalike
---

Authors say many things [@aaroe11].
```

[image]

This is the reference entry in the .bib file:

```
@article{aaroe11,
Author = {Lene Aaroe},
Date-Added = {2017-03-14 00:40:32 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2017-03-28 22:17:31 +0000},
Journal = {Political Communication},
Number = {2},
Pages = {207-226},
Title = {Investigating Frame Strength: The Case of Episodic and Thematic Frames},
Volume = {28},
Year = {2011}}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem - this has only just started happening so may be a bug with the latest release of... rmarkdown(?)

Comment: Your example works perfectly fine here. If this hasn't solved itself, add `keep_tex: true` to the output settings of the `.rmd` file (see http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html#keeping_intermediate_tex), and try compiling the `.tex` file manually using e.g. TeXworks, or the command line. For `file.tex` You need to run `pdflatex file` then `bibtex file`, then `pdflatex file` twice.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that this was still open, Torbjorn! The problem has solved itself now - although the solution wasn't anything to do with R or markdown itself. I had a feeling it was something to do with the make-up of my .bib file, so I ran all the references through Zotero and exported a new .bib. With that file, natbib worked perfectly. I don't know what exactly was wrong with the original .bib file, but there you go. I don't like not knowing what the error was, but at least the solution is simple enough. I've marked the question as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by doing a fresh install of the `knitr` package from `Github`:

```
devtools::install_github('yihui/knitr')
```

Comment: That didn't work for me. I also tried an update of the `rmarkdown` package, then a fresh install of `knitr`. Didn't work either. Is the rest of your setup the same as mine, i.e `biblio-style: apalike` etc.?

Comment: The problem came back, and this time I found that the reason was a duplicated reference in my .bib file. I deleted the refs in the .Rmd file one by one until I found the one causing the problem, but you could just manually look through your .bib file to look for duplicated entries (the `@...` component would be the same, which was causing the bug in my case)

Comment: I definitely don't have any duplicated references in my .bib

Comment: Are you still having this problem? If so, could you upload your .bib file somewhere and provide a link to download it?

Comment: Yes, it still doesn't work. Here is the dropbox link to download the .bib file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ttpgdud6ernfxl0/framingstudy.bib?dl=0

Comment: In your .bib file, the reference is `aaroe11`, not `aaroe`. Therefore, you should write `Authors say many things [@aaroe11].`, which should work

Comment: My apologies, the code snippets I provided should have said `aaroe11` all along; I made a mistake when copying from my .Rmd. I fixed them now. Trust me, that wasn't the issue; I have been using the correct reference, which is why it worked without `natbib`. I tried updating `rmarkdown` again, no change.

Comment: It seems to have been something to do with the .bib file (see comment above), so a fresh install should generally do the trick. I've marked the question as answered